# How to load data in ChoiceType choices options from the database

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want to build a form with ChoiceType and the option values/choices are based on database table (with records already).

When the form displayed, the list of religions will be available at the dropdown list/combo box.

Example :

```
 $builder->add('name',  ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices' => $religions //List of religions 
    ));
```

So far here are my codes:

```
class Religion
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50)
 */
protected $name;

/*** getter/setter ... ***/
}
```

/Form/ReligionType

```
class ReligionType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name',  ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices' =>  ____________ 
    ));
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Religion'
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'app_bundle_religion_type';
}
}
```

/Controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/religion/select", name="religion_select")
 *
 */
public function selectAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $religions = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Religion')->findAll();


    $form = $this->createForm(ReligionType::class, ________);

    return $this->render(
        'religion/index.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        )
    );
}
```

I don't really know what to write so i leave it as __________ and what are the missing codes.

/ReligionRepository

```
class ReligionRepository extends EntityRepository
{
public function findAll()
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT p FROM AppBundle:Religion p ORDER BY p.name ASC'
        )
        ->getResult();
}
}
```

/Twig File

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
<button type="submit">Save</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What about using the `EntityType`, which specifically is made to integrate with the database: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Answer (score 5):

as suggested by Rvanlaak, here's the solution.

```
 //ReligionType
 $builder->add('religions',  EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Religion',
                'choice_label' => 'name'
    ));

 //Controller
public function newAction(Request $request)
{

    $religion = new Religion();
    $form = $this->createForm(ReligionType::class, $religion);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($religion);
        $em->flush();

        //return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
    }


    return $this->render(
        'religion/new.html.twig',
        array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I did like this:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('currency', null, [
                    'expanded'  => true,
                     'multiple' => true,
                     'label' => 'Currency'
            ])
```

In my entity like this:

```
protected $currency;
 /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->Currency = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

/**
 * @param \MyBundle\Entity\Currency $Currency
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function addCurrency(\MyBundle\Entity\Currency $Currency)
{
    $this->Currency[] = $Currency;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove Currency
 *
 * @param \MyBundle\Entity\Currency $Currency
 */
public function removeCurrency(\MyBundle\Entity\Currency $Currency)
{
    $this->Currency->removeElement($Currency);
}

/**
 * Get Currency
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getCurrency()
{
    return $this->Currency;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both posted solutions didn't work for me because the `ChoiceType` type was removed from it. Here is a solution with the ChoiceType still existing:

I wanted to generate a list with types of absents users can choose from. These types are created by a user in the system settings. I first load them from db, then create one array (for loop) with where the `["name"]` will be the name the user sees. The `id` is the value that the html select field will have and return when selected and saved.

What I added and could not find anywhere was the extra option to pass an option in the `createForm` function. This enables you to send data to the form basicly.

```php
$systemAbsents = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(SystemAbsent::class)->getAllNonDeletedSystemAbsents();

$choices = [];

// Add each choice to the list. The id's have to match correctly so the html choicetype will return the chosen id that then will be saved in the db.
for ($i = 0; $i < count($systemAbsents); $i++) {
    $choices += [$systemAbsents[$i]["name"] => $systemAbsents[$i]["id"]];
}

$absent = new Absent();

// Create form and pass the choices to later connect them with the ChoiceType field.
$form = $this->createForm(AbsentType::class, $absent, ['choices' => $choices]);
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

Then in the form, you can use the data and pass it to the `'choices'` option.

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $this->choices = $options['choices'];

    $builder
        ->add('choices', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => $this->choices,
            'label_attr' => [
                'class' => 'bold',
            ],
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'input-margin select-field w-100',
            ],
            'mapped' => false,
        ])
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'choices' => [],
    ]);
}
```

The array I create in the for loop looks like this:

```php
[
  "absent-type-1" => 10
  "absent-type-2" => 11
  "absent-type-3" => 12
  "absent-type-4" => 13
  "absent-type-5" => 14
  "absent-type-6" => 15
  "absent-type-7" => 16
  "absent-type-8" => 17
]
```

The ID starts at 10 because I deleted some while testing.

If you by default want to show a `selected` value in the `ChoiceType` field you can do `setData` **after** you create the form. Like this:

```php
// Create form
$form = $this->createForm(AbsentType::class, $absent, ['choices' => $choices]);

// Add this line to set a default. But make sure you pass the value equal to the html `value` attribute.
$form->get('system_absents')->setData($absent->getSystemAbsentID());
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

There is a possiblity you get an `Array to string conversion` error. I dont know how exactly this works but i've once used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51744484/symfony-form-choicetype-error-array-to-string-covnersion) before.