# Symfony 5 - Notice: Array to string conversion in user create form because of roles

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I'm having trouble solving this problem, when i get in the page for creating a user in my Symfony web app, the user controller complains about the createForm() function and the error only says "Notice: Array to string conversion".

The form is the default created with the crud, actually everything is almost default so I can´t think on a single reason this thing doesn´t work as intended.

I've tried to modify the form to use a multiple selection but that didn´t work either.

And I tried to modify the data type in the entity but that just didn´t even worked because it throwed an error in the file immediately.

Here is the UserType.php (form generator)

```
namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email')
            ->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label' => 'Tipo de usuario',
                'attr' => [
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'class'=>'form-control myselect'
                ],
                'choices'  => [
                    'Admin' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
                    'Usuario' => 'ROLE_USER'
                ],
            
            ])
            ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Password'),
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The user controller in the breackpoint where Symfony shows the error:

```
     /**
     * @Route("/new", name="user_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function new(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder): Response
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);  // <-- This is the highlighted part.
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $user->setPassword(
                $passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
                    $user,
                    $form->get('plainPassword')->getData()
                )
            );

            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('user_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

        return $this->render('user/new.html.twig', [
            'user' => $user,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

And the user entity in the fragments where i declare the role variable and the getter and setter:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="json")
 */
 private $roles = [];
 


 /**
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function getRoles(): array
{
    $roles = $this->roles;
    // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
    $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

    return array_unique($roles);
}

public function setRoles(array $roles): self
{
    $this->roles = $roles;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51744484/symfony-form-choicetype-error-array-to-string-covnersion help ?

Comment: On which line do you get this notice?

Comment: @nacholibre in the one that says "This is the highlighted part"

Answer (score 1):

`$roles` is an array, you can see it in your configuration :

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="json")
 */
 private $roles = [];
```

Even if we have `type="json"`, it will be used as an array but in your database it will be a regular json.

**ChoiceType** here is a string so you can't use it in `$roles`.

You can add a [data transformer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) ([see similar response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51744484/symfony-form-choicetype-error-array-to-string-covnersion)) to convert the value when displaying it in your select or when using it with your entity.

The simple way to do it is using a CallBackTransformer directly in your form type :

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\CallbackTransformer;

$builder->get('roles')
    ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
        fn ($rolesAsArray) => count($rolesAsArray) ? $rolesAsArray[0]: null,
        fn ($rolesAsString) => [$rolesAsString]
));
```

Or if your are not using PHP 7.4+

```
$builder->get('roles')
    ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
        function ($rolesAsArray) {
             return count($rolesAsArray) ? $rolesAsArray[0]: null;
        },
        function ($rolesAsString) {
             return [$rolesAsString];
        }
));
```